# Create Sqlite db in PublisherCacheFolder

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

For my sample Uwp app I want to create sqlite db in SqLightDataBase in Publisher Cache Folder like:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Publishers\temp_folder\SqLightDataBase, because I want multiply uwp app from same Publisher be able to use it.
I refer to:

- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/#vyPW3Qg7IwfWxchx.97
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#use-data
- https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/#bFwwp4tUPHe0OwDj.97
- https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/wiki/Connection-Strings

According to above: The sqlite file 'is created on the fly the first time it’s called, and is stored in the application’s local data store.'
My sample code:

```
string path = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.GetPublisherCacheFolder("SqLightDataBase").Path, "sqliteSample.db");                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
        }

        var sqliteConnectionString = "DataSource=" + path;

        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection(sqliteConnectionString))
        {
            db.Open();

            String tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT " +
                                    "EXISTS MyTable (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                    "Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";

            SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);

            createTable.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

**Package.appmanifest**

```
<Extension Category="windows.publisherCacheFolders">
  <PublisherCacheFolders>
    <Folder Name="SqLightDataBase"/>
  </PublisherCacheFolders>
</Extension>
```

Solution has two projects:

1. Universal Windows Class Library
2. Universal Windows App

Both target to Win 10 version 1803, and min Win 10 Creators Update

Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 1.1.1
- Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.1.7

**Error**
When try to `db.Open();` I get:

> SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

I tried to Create a db file before Open it but current API doesn't provide this option. Also I am able to copy db file from Local to Publisher folder, but it is not ideal solution.
Is there any way to force SqliteConnection to create db file in PublisherCacheFolder instead in Local ones 'on the fly'?

Comment: The same code works in my side, and this is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/DBTest.git), please check if other issue cause this problem such the operation system issue.

Comment: I did exactly same project like yours, and yes it works. I started testing it. When I delete SqLightDataBase and run app again  the folder hasn't been created. So I created SqLightDataBase folder manually. Run again, and got same error. Finally I compared two folders new(created manually) and old(in Bin), and I spotted that the new one didn't have user ids related to the app with permissions to work on the folder. To sum up, I should have not removed old SqLightDataBase folder.

Comment: Your mean that delete the old `SqLightDataBase` cause this issue?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: If you have solved your issue. you could post your answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by restoring SqLightDataBase folder (which has all permissions for my sample UWP app) from the bin back to PublisherCacheFolder.